# Lightslider - first img not showing until window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am facing a strange thing. I am using lightslider to display my img-s. Now when I use it inside the regular dom, so the one that is open everything works fine. But sometimes I show a modal window on top of my regular one, and there I have the problem that the first img is never shown. I can scroll to the others, but when I comes to select the show the first one, it appears for a second and then dissapears. After some trying a found out that when I resize the browser window (by hand) for just one pixel then I am able to select the first img (if it was already selected but not visible it appears on its own)

Does anybody know what the reason could be, or if not, how can I simulate the behaviour of the window resize (that would be the quick and dirty solution) ?

Regards

Comment: hmm, thats a bit complicated bcz its part of a bigger thing, but I will see to create smt

Comment: I got it here: https://jsfiddle.net/vd1phq0n/ , the problem with this one is just that it doenst show up at all. When I resize it it shows up, but then I cant show my problem (bcz resizing fixes my problem too)

Comment: but even like that, when you resize it, you can see that not the first but the second img is selected

Comment: I updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vd1phq0n/3/) but I cannot understand. I added the wimdow resize event... I'm sorry.

Answer (score 5):

you can put this `$( window ).resize();` after the script. That should work. However you can use the following code snippet too:

```
onSliderLoad: function() {
    $( window ).resize();
}, onAfterSlide: function() {
    $( window ).resize();
}
```

don't use too many this script `$( window ).resize();`  ,because jquery will display error  "exceeded RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" , if it shows that error, just use one `$( window ).resize();`

Comment: thank you very much !! i've been searching for this solution dor days now

Answer (score 1):

Anyone still having this issue with a carousel.. A quick fix is by toggling between ID's, one of which has "height:0px" and overflow hidden. This one really really killed me so hope it helps someone out there.

```
#demo {
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0px;



}
#demo_visible {
  overflow: hidden;
}


   jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $(".arrow_link").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

    if ($(".demo").attr('id') == 'demo_visible') {

                $(".demo").attr('id', 'demo');

            } else {

                $(".demo").attr('id', 'demo_visible');

            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can put $(window).resize(); after the lightSlider() script.

You can use the following code snippet too:

```
setTimeout(() => {$( window ).resize()}, 500);
```

Here you can use setTimeout Function, because some time script executed before load the DOM.